# Problem with @storybook/addon-info and @material-ui/core

Tags: storybook

I have a story of `Button.jsx`

```
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

storiesOf('Button', module)
  .add('default', () => {
    const disabled = boolean(...);
    const children = text(...);
    const color = select(...);
    const size = select(...);

    return (
      <Button disabled={disabled} size={size} color={color} onClick={action('clicked')}>
        {children}
      </Button>
    );
  })
```

When I run my storybook with `addon-info` I getting this instead of my really code

[image]

Are there ways to set own `Story Source`?